# How to know which node:alpine image version is in running container

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, alpine-linux

I have one running container which uses node:alpine as base image.I want to know version of this image.

Comment: you mean node version?

Comment: is docker command not accessible?

Comment: I want to change Dockerfile to use node:alpine to use the static version which is running in this container.

Comment: `docker image inspect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the **Dockerfile** of the container if handy.

You can check the first line with **FROM** `node:<version>-alpine`

For example :

```
FROM node:12.18.1-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
```

You can also use the command `docker image inspect`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_inspect/

You can also **exec** into the container to check the version of **Node**

**Command to check node version:**

```
docker exec -ti <Container name> sh -c "node --version"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running the command FROM `node:<version>-alpine`

You can also try running the command `alpine -v` or `alpine -version` .You can also start Alpine and press? on the main menu to open the main Help page, which will also tell you the version.

Refer to the [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) for more information.